# How to verify the signature of python method when using Default parameters?

Tags: python

Is there a way to check if all the argument passes to a method matches the expected one ? I tried the inspect.signature.bind to match them but it does now work properly when using a default parameter, even when the type of the default value is not same as passed. e.g. in the last call to the method faa, I send a list as the third argument, but the expected default argument is Bool. Is there a way to match that also ?

```
import inspect
def foo(a, b, x=True):
    pass

def faa(*args, **kwargs):
  try:
    inspect.signature(foo).bind(*args, **kwargs)
  except TypeError:
    print("Does not match")
  else:
    print("Matches")  


faa(1)                     # Does not match , Ok
faa(10, None, 'something') # Matches, Ok.
faa(1, 2)                  # Matches, Ok.
faa(10, None, [1,2])       # Matches, NOK. Is there a way to add a check to not match ?
```

Comment: So you want to check if the argument types match?

Comment: Yes, Is there a way to check the types in such cases where the type of the default value is not same as the passed ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define a simple decorator that can be used for every function you want to validate. This decorator builds up on the `inpsect` module. The idea is to validate the function parameter (both positional and non-positional) against the default value of the corresponding argument in the function.

```
import inspect
from functools import wraps

def validate_func_args(func):
    def check_type(value, fn_param: inspect.Parameter):
        if not fn_param.default is fn_param.empty:
            _default = fn_param.default
            # We do not type check if the default value is None or if the argument is none
            is_none = _default is None or value is None

            if not is_none and type(value) != type(_default):
                raise TypeError(f"Invalid type encountered for {fn_param.name}")

    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        # Validate parameters with default values
        args_count = len(args)
        fn_params = inspect.signature(foo).parameters

        for arg, param in zip(args, list(fn_params)[:args_count]):
            check_type(arg, fn_params[param])

        for kwarg, value in kwargs.items():
            check_type(value, fn_params[kwarg])

        # All good. Now call the function and return the result
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        return result

    return wrapper
```

Function definition

```
@validate_func_args
def foo(a, b=2, x=True):
    pass
```

Function call

```
foo(10, None, "something")
```

Output

```
TypeError: Invalid type encountered for x
```

Comment: Call to first pass is not necessary, or is it ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the decorator `validate_arguments` belonging to the module `pydantic`. As an example:

```
from pydantic import validate_arguments


@validate_arguments
def faa(a, b, x: bool = True):
    pass


faa(
    a=10, b=None, x=[1, 2]
)
```

Output

```
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for Faa
x
  value could not be parsed to a boolean (type=type_error.bool)
```

Comment: This is an option surely. I was looking for something more generic which can be applied to easily to especially because I have many such method to be checked and I do not want to  change every one of them.